# Firebase throws exception on initializeApp, "Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, firebase

I tried downgrading my flutter, happens on every version I tried. Downgraded my firebase_core and firebase_auth dependencies, still same problem. Installed fedora on my other drive just to make sure I didn't mess anything on my main system, still happens there as well.

Even if I don't run with debug mode and just use flutter run, using any sign in or sign out function will freeze the app since Firebase.initializeApp doesn't initialize.

Flutter doctor doesn't show any problems.

main.dart:

```
 void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      runApp(const MainApp());
    }
```

Firebase.initializeApp, throws this exception:

> Exception has occurred. "Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but
> got one of type 'Null'
> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 288:49      throw*
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 121:3       castError
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 529:12  cast
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 78:24
> as packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 87:20
> get [_ignoredServiceScripts]
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 163:28
> _initializeCore dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54
> runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 155:31
> [_initializeCore]
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 197:11
> initializeApp
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54
> runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async
> packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 193:44
> initializeApp packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 43:47
> initializeApp
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54
> runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart
> 39:43                                    initializeApp
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54
> runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 123:5                _async
> web_entrypoint.dart 24:31
>
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 367:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart
> 372:39  dcall lib/ui/initialization.dart 77:15
>  dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart
> 45:50                 dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54
> runUnary dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18
> handleValue dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44
> handleValueCallback dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13
> _propagateToListeners dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                         [_completeWithValue] dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7
> callback dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11
> _microtaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15
>  "

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS Code, check if you have "All Exceptions" checked off under the breakpoints section. I had this same problem and unchecking it fixed it for me.